# SqlAlchemy select expression data types

Tags: sqlalchemy

With SqlAlchemy I am using the select public_factory to build my queries as such:

```
from sqlalchemy import select

table_cols = ['cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'date', 'name']
qry = select(table_cols)
conn = db.get_engine()
sql = "{}".format(
    qry.compile(
        conn, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True},),)
```

Cat, Dog and Frog are type Float, data is date and name is type String. The returned qry expression is

```
SELECT "cat", "dog", "frog", date, name
```

Note that date and name are note quoted, I can understand why date is not returned as a string but unsure why name is not.

Otherwise I could use some sore of hack like this but would rather not:

```
def select_specific(table_name, column_list):
    sql = list()
    sql.append("SELECT ")
    for i, item in enumerate(column_list):
        if i == len(column_list)-1:
            sql.append("'{0}' ".format(item)) 
        else:
            sql.append("'{0}', ".format(item)) 
    sql.append("FROM {0}".format(table_name))
    sql.append(";")
    return "".join(sql)
```

Any thoughts on how I can generating a select statement using sqlalchemy that handles any type of column?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using manual generation of SQL using the following as a basis:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577605-auto-generate-simple-sql-statements/